# Create controls in UIView at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitextfield

I have one UITextField and a button in a view.

1. Once a button is pressed, value in text field need to be searched fieldID column in core data table and get value[comma separated].
2. Separate the string by comma and assign values to array.
3. A new UIView needs to be inserted in the main screen and place N number[count of array] of labels and textfields and align.

I am able to do 1, 2 and UIView creation.

Can anybody help me to create N number of controls in sub UIView at runtime?

Comment: in swift or objective C???

Comment: You shouldn't feel forced to re-edit your title and add "Swift" again if people answered in Objective-C instead of Swift as you specified in the tags. Language tag goes in the tags; title goes in the title. Thank you for your understanding and sorry if the edit war was confusing.

Comment: As i am not able to reply Dheeraj, so i have updated title :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i=0;i<self.yourArray.count; i++)
  {
      UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,80*i+60,self.view.frame.size.width-20,60)];
      label.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:i];
      [self.view addSubview:label];
  }
```

> Please Explain your problem more clearly !

Comment: I have to create  a UIView and add uilabels and uitextfields as many as elements in array.

Comment: try my code which is creating UILabel programmatically, you can add also UITextField this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
May be your array count is very large so take a scroll view also in your view   

 UIScrollView* yourScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yourView.frame.origin.x, yourView.frame.origin.y,yourView.frame.size.width,yourView.frame.size.height)];
        for(int i= 0; i< 10;i++)
        {
            UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 50, 21)];
            lbl.text = @"";
            UITextField* txtField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl.frame.origin.x+10 , y, 200, 21)];
            txtField.text = @"";
            [yourScrollView addSubview:lbl];
            [yourScrollView addSubview:txtField];
            y = y+30;
        }
    [yourView addSubview:yourScrollView];
```

Comment: Can you provide in swift

Comment: i'm sorry. i don't have more knowledge about swift.

Comment: Np. I cannot use scrollview. The UIview height has to be increased based on the number elements in array.

Comment: check y value if it is greater then your screen size then set content size of scrollview else set it equal view height

Comment: if y is less then screen height then set your view height equal to y+label height